# How to change the folder icon in Windows 10 Quick Access?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In Windows 7 Favorites in Explorer, one could change the icons of the folders that were pinned there. For instance, I liked to be able to change the GitHub folder to a GitHub icon: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AWorldOfPrettyCloudDriveIconsSkyDriveGoogleDriveDropboxBitBucketAndGitHub.aspx

Windows 10 introduced the "Quick Access", and while I can add my GitHub folder to the Quick Access bar, I can't seem to change the icon. Right clicking and choosing "Properties", then changing the icon results in the icon of the folder in the main Explorer window changing, but not the icon of the Quick Access folder.

How can I change the icon of the Quick Access folder?

Comment: After changing the icon, have you tried to unpin then re-pin the folder to the Quick Access?

Comment: @DrZoo That does indeed solve the problem. Thank you! Will you write it up as an answer so you can have the credit? Of course, the follow up question is, how to set the icon only in the Quick Access and not on the referenced folder as well...

Comment: Glad the problem is solved. I added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After changing the icon, you have to unpin then re-pin the folder to the Quick Access so the icon will update.